# Is it possible to use Eclipse with Pydev without having rights to run programs in cmd?

Tags: eclipse, cmd, pydev

Is it possible to use Eclipse with Pydev without having rights to run programs in cmd? If so, how to do that?

(I plan to teach Python in my school but the studens do not have rights to run programs in cmd.)

\Hokan

Comment: Likely no. However, why are you dragging `cmd` into this? Could you give some more detail? I'm *guessing* that the workstations are restricted to only running certain applications, but that has nothing to do with `cmd` – it's a domain-wide setting through group policies. In that case you can just talk to the administrators and ask them to allow whatever you need tor teaching.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use jython to teach python.

jython runs on the jvm and if eclipse can used it is possible that jython can used too

Comment: In fact, PyDev include Jython as part of its installation.